# is there a way to ignore spaces at the beginning of filtering for datatables?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am using the jquery plugin [Datables](http://www.datatables.net/index) and I am using the php processing file to do filtering. I have already modified the code to allow for multiple keywords.but if I input a space as a starting char I get a JSON error is it possible to ignore this error without having to click ok? or is there a way to modify the php to allow spaces to start.

thanks

heres some code:

```
 $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "")
    {
            $aWords = preg_split('/\s+/', $_GET['sSearch']);
            $sWhere = "WHERE (";

            for ( $j=0 ; $j<count($aWords) ; $j++ )
            {
                    if ( $aWords[$j] != "" )
                    {
                            if(substr($aWords[$j], 0, 1) == "!"){
                                    $notString = substr($aWords[$j], 1);
                                    $sWhere .= "(";
                                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                                            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." NOT LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $notString )."%' AND ";
                                    }
                                    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -4 );
                            }
                            else{
                                    $sWhere .= "(";
                                    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ ) {
                                            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $aWords[$j] )."%' OR ";
                                    }
                                    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
                            }
                            $sWhere .= ") AND ";
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `preg_split()` operating on a single-space string:

```
$e = preg_split('/\s+/', " ");
print_r($e);
```

Splitting a single space will return an array of two blank strings. Change the first lines to this:

```
$term = trim($_GET['sSearch']);
if ( $term != "")
{
        $aWords = preg_split('/\s+/', $term);
```

This way, you don't try and run the code with a basically blank string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where the json error occurs as you are only showing the php, but both php and jQuery offer functions to trim whitespace from the beginning and the end of a string.

In your javascript, before the rest of the processing, you could do:

```
my_string = $.trim(original_string);
```

And in php you can do:

```
$aWords = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($_GET['sSearch']));
// or use trim on the individual words of the result...
```